# Runtime error: "must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" when launching a QDialog from a dll built with static Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dll, static-libraries

I built a static version of Qt from the VS2015 command line with the following:

```
..\Src\configure -prefix E:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\QtStatic -static -static-runtime -nomake tests -nomake examples -debug-and-release -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -opengl desktop
```

I use Cmake to build my main application and a dll, using the /MTd option and linking (in debug mode) all the "*d.lib" files in the Qt /lib and /plugins/platforms directories and the C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Lib/x64 folder.

My main function:

```
#include "myWindowClass.h"
#include <QApplication.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    myWindowClass *mwc = new myWindowClass();
    mwc->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

myWindowClass.h (STATIC_BUILD is defined in Cmake):

```
#pragma once
#include <QMainWindow.h>
#include "ui_mainWindow.h"
#include <QtPlugin>
#include <QLibrary>
#include "myDllClass.h"

#ifdef STATIC_BUILD
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin)
#endif

typedef MyDllClass* (*MyDll)();

namespace Ui {
    class myWindowClass;
}

class myWindowClass : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myWindowClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myWindowClass() {
        delete ui;
    }

public slots:
    void launchMyDialog();
    void loadMyDll();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLibrary *lib;
    MyDllClass *myc;
};
```

myWindowClass.cpp:

```
#include "myWindowClass.h"

myWindowClass::myWindowClass(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void myWindowClass::launchMyDialog() {
    if (lib)
        if (lib->isLoaded())
            myc->launchDialog();
}

myWindowClass::loadMyDll() {
    lib = new QLibrary("MyDLL.dll");
    lib->load();
    if (lib->isLoaded()) { // Library is found to be loaded
        auto create = (MyDll)lib.resolve("Create");
        if (create)  // Create resolves successfully
            myc = create(); // create executes successfully
    }

}
```

I constructed a mainWindow.ui with Qt Designer that has buttons connected to the loadMyDll() and launchMyDialog() functions.

In myDllClass.h:

```
#if defined (WIN32) && defined (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
#if defined (_MSC_VER)
#pragma warning(disable: 4251)
#endif
#if defined(MyDLL_EXPORT)
#define  MYLIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define  MYLIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define MYLIB_EXPORT
#endif

struct MyDllClass {
    virtual void launchDialog() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public MyDllClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    ~MyClass() {}
    void launchDialog();
};
```

In myDllClass.cpp:

```
#include "myDllClass.h"
#include "MyDialog.h"

MyClass::launchDialog() {
    myDialogClass *pDllDialog = new myDialogClass(); // Runtime error  "QWidget: must construct a QApplication before a QWidget"
    pDllDialog->raise();
    pDllDialog->activateWindow();
    pDllDialog->exec();
}

extern "C" MYLIB_EXPORT MyDllClass * Create() {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

In myDialog.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_MyDialog.h"

class myDialogClass : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myDialogClass(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog) {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    ~myDialogClass() {
        delete ui;
    }

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

Also with Qt Designer, I constructed a myDialog.ui with only the OK and Cancel buttons.

The error appears at the point indicated.  Setting breakpoints inside the constructor of myDialogClass shows that the first line, ui->setupUi(this), is never reached; the failure is happening before that.

Note that this code, built with the /MDd option and using the Qt dlls, runs okay.  Building MyDLL as a static library and linking it also runs okay (by calling Create() directly rather than resolving it first).  It is only in using a static build of Qt to build MyDLL as a dll that I run into problems.

Is this something that can be done?  And if so, where am I going wrong?

Things that I tried that did not work, or would not build:  including the Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN macro in myDialog.h; trying to construct a new QApplication inside the dll; building in release /MT with release libs.

Things that I haven't tried:  mixing static and shared versions of the Qt builds between the main app and MyDLL; mixing static and shared versions of Qt and the runtime libraries.  That wouldn't really interest me:  the point is to have an application that doesn't rely on Qt or runtime dlls.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in MyClass::launchDialog (on the first line, before the call to `new`) to see where that's getting called from.

Comment: The first line of MyClass::launchDialog is myDialogClass *pDllDialog = new myDialogClass().  It is on the execution of that line that the error occurs.

Comment: Another way I attempted was implicit linking of the dll.  This also generated the same error at the same location.

Comment: Another attempt:  passing "this" from myWindowClass to the QDialog constructor via myDllClass.  Same error, same location.

Comment: do you link your app with qt and the dll that has qt in it statically?

Comment: So, further reading indicates that trying to build dlls with static runtime (/MT) invite all kinds of difficulty having to do with managing separate dynamic memory heaps across dll boundaries, of which this may be a manifestation.  Static linking is apparently an all-or-nothing proposition:  either build your application as One Big Executable, or use the dynamic runtime and the Qt dlls.